# Identifying the group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I am defining a matrix group in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/). I know that its a finite group, and can compute its order. Using `sonata` package and commands like `AllGroups( Size( G ) )` and  `IsIsomorphicGroup( G, H )` commands, I can find the Group-ID in the GAP database.

I would like to identify this group with a **well-known** group like Dihedral, Quaternion, Cyclic, etc. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
m1 := [[0,-1],[1,0]] ;
m2 := [[0,1],[1,0]] ;
G := Group( m1, m2 );
Size( G );
```

One option I can think is to define these *standard* groups and check if $G$ is isomorphic to any of them! For example,

```
IsCyclic( G ); # This is easy!
Q := QuaternionGroup( Size( G ) );
IsIsomorphicGroup( G, Q );
D := DihedralGroup( Size( G ) );
IsIsomorphicGroup( G, D );
```

I know the term **well-known** is a vague, but these are the groups, I would understand from my textbook!

A possible (vague) general question can be asked, are there **named** groups in GAP?

Comment: I usually use StructureDescription(G)

Comment: From the manual of `StructureDescription`: Note that `StructureDescription` is not intended to be a research tool, but rather an educational tool.

Comment: Note also ["Can non-isomorphic groups have equal structure descriptions?"](https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.12) from the GAP F.A.Q. Also, performance of `StructureDescription` may depend on the way how the group is represented - fp and matrix groups may be slower that pc and permutation groups.

Comment: You can find the index in the small groups library easier with `IdGroup`.

Comment: What is a _standard_ group is very subjective, beyond a handfull of small examples. There are libraries of groups in GAP that have names, but some names are specific to the library (even just: Number $x$ in the library), and classification provided by the library might involve actions and not only isomorphism.

Comment: A plug for a webpage of my colleague Tim Dokchitser: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/. Descriptions and impressively much information about impressively many groups of order up to 500, which you can find by their SmallGroups ID. Not all of them, of course.

Comment: @Easy, the command `StructureDescription` is what I was looking for, as my usage was meant only for the demo / learning purpose. So I dont care much about the performance.

Comment: @ahulpke,  The command `IdGroup` does not give much information, beyond the ID in the GAP database.  The online manual doesnt have anything on `IdGroup`. The inbuilt manual is a on-liner.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, the links looks quite interesting.

Comment: @user5325. In general, the Id number *is* the only name (you asked for a general method) for a group, unless you want to introduce your own.

Answer (score 2):

You might notice that $m_2$ and $m_1m_2$ both have order two, and your group is certainly generated by $m_2$ and $m_1m_2$, therefore, it must be dihedral. (In this case, of order $8$, since $m_1$ has order $4$.)